# What is the best way to fetch data while costructing a Xamarin Page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin app which talks to a BLE device. Currently I am building something like a "file explorer"; I have a page with a list view of 3 "file types" that can be downloaded from the device; when an item is tapped I would like to create a new page (using `Navigation.PushAsync()`) with a list of files fetched from the device. I'm implementing it using a page which create and bind to its viewmodel in its constructor but I can't call the async method for downloading data in the constructor.

Is this bad design or is there a way to start the informations download during the creation of the viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your data id beign downloaded, you can open the new page with an activity indicator bounded to an `IsBusy` property from YourViewModel.

Then you can start your download on a new task, like this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    private bool isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => isBusy;
        set => SetProperty(isBusy, value);
    }

    public YourViewModel()
    {
        StartDownload();
    }

    private void StartDownload()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        Task.Run(ExceptionHandler(async() => 
            {
              // Your download starts here
              // await it
              // and when it came finished:
              Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
            }));
    }

    private void ExceptionHandler(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

You can add the page components through events from view model or something like that.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't know of the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`; just for info, could I also call `isBusy = false;` instead of `IsBusy = false;` being executed on the main thread?

Comment: @ArenaLor, it's not a problem of threads, but if you use isBusy = true, your View won't be notified of the property change, that will be triggered only when updating the property, assuming of course you are using some MVVM framework or manually calling PropertyChanged from the set accessor of the IsBusy property (the SetProperty method of the given answer just do that, I suppose, that is changing the value of isBusy and notify the clients, and in fact comes built in with many frameworks).

Comment: @FrancescoBlue answered perfectly well, THANKS . SetProperty is about notifying property changes. I'm also assuming you're using the MVVM approach.

Comment: Thank you @FrancescoBlue and @Diego Rafael Souza; I've got a little issue with this; if during the download (inside the `Task.Run`) an exception is throw, despite the `try/catch` block I used the exception is not caught

Comment: @ArenaLor you can't handle exceptions with a `try\catch` block outside the thread. You can do it as I've suggested, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you can define a `LoadDataAsync` method in your ViewModel, and call it from the OnAppearing method of your view. You have to mark this as async:

```
public class MyView : ContenPage {

    private bool isDataLoaded = false;

    public void MyView {
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing(){
        if (!isDataLoaded && BindingContext is MyViewModel vm){
            await vm.LoadDataAsync();
            isDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `isDataLoaded` field: setting this to `true` after fetching data avoid to fetch data again when navigating back from another page (this can or cannot be useful depending on your application logic).

In your `LoadDataAsync` method in the ViewModel, you can then insert your fetching data code in a normal try / catch block.

Comment: The only problem is that after calling `await vm.LoadDataAsync();` the list doesn't get updated; should I be doing something else the "refresh" the property?

Comment: Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly in your ViewModel?

Comment: Yeah I use the same `INotifyPropertyChanged` in all of my ViewModels without problems. I use another property from the viewModel, `IsDownloading` to control is an ActivityIndicator should be visible, and that works correctly: the spinner is visible and running during the data download, but then the list appears to be empty (vs. when I call the download method from the constructor using Task.Run it gets loaded correcly)

Comment: It seems adding in the list inside a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method is working.

Comment: Yes, in theory property updates that impact on UI refresh should be done on the main thread. But in reality I used this pattern a lot of times without worring about that and everything worked fine. It was always on Android though. Maybe you are working on iOS? I have heard iOS is more picky about requesting everything UI-related being always on the main thread.